# What was the role of Nigeria in Soviet invasion of Afghanistan

Tags: soviet-union, cold-war, afghanistan

I'm required to present a report on the role and position of Nigeria on the Soviet  invasion of Afghanistan. But as far as I know , Nigeria had a civil war raging inside the country.

I've scanned through hundreds of website & articles but none of them provided solid evidence that Nigeria did play an important role in the invasion

My question is , did Nigeria in any affected the Soviet invasion of Afghanistan  , what were its effects & how it came about

Also , who were the allies of Nigeria during period of 1969-1970 and how did the allies support them and vice versa

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Are you sure that Nigeria is supposed to have played an important role in the invasion? A quick google search suggests that Nigerians were ["the most vociferous African critics"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E8CzZkOwCNIC&pg=PA213) of the Soviet invasion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a cold war tale.  Nigerian Prime Minister [Abubakar Tarawa Balewa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abubakar_Tafawa_Balewa) 1960-1966 was pro-western.  When he was overthrown in a military coup and murdered January 15, 1966, it sparked a counter coup, and the [Nigerian Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigerian_Civil_War) (July 6, 1967 – January 15, 1970).  During the Civil War the Soviets were a major arms supplier to the government, beginning the relationship which would turn into political support in the '70s.

In the 1970s Nigeria's relationship with the west began to lapse.  During this same time Nigeria found itself on the same side of several issues as the Soviet Union.  Nigeria was very critical of the white regimes in southern Africa, South African and Rhodesia.  The Soviet Union was supporting nationalist movements in both countries and this put them on the same side of these issues.  Nigeria sided with the Soviet Union throughout the '70s on such issues as action against apartheid, recognition of the MPLA in Angola, and immediate independence for Namibia.

All this interaction between Nigeria and the Soviet Union made the west pretty concerned that Nigeria was becoming a Soviet satellite state.  The Soviet Invasion of Afghanistan was a reordering episode.  Nigeria became a vocal critic of the Soviet invasion.  Distance was placed between Nigeria and the Soviet Union and a rapprochement with the west ensued.

**Sources:**

- **[Abubakar Tafawa Balewa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abubakar_Tafawa_Balewa)**
- **[Nigerian Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigerian_Civil_War)**
- **[No Easy Row for a Russian Hoe: Ideology and Pragmatism in Nigerian-Soviet](https://books.google.com/books?id=qnfyZ7rHbtoC&pg=PA154&dq=nigeria+soviet+invasion+of+afghanistan&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip-pi_6u_cAhUEheAKHfcdCskQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=nigeria%20soviet%20invasion%20of%20afghanistan&f=false)**

Comment: Did Nigeria send troops, advisors, money, or any resources, then recall them? Did they provide any material support at all?

Comment: No,  Nigeria was a vocal critic of the Invasion from the beginning.  The invasion was  Dec 24, 1979,  When the UN debated the invasion Jan 12 1980,  Nigeria was already critical.  [India Supports Soviets' Afghan Position in U.N. Debate](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1980/01/12/india-supports-soviets-afghan-position-in-un-debate/17dd1eb5-93f9-44bf-9f95-ecda7285843c/?utm_term=.f27831e8c20a) P. Akporode Clark of Nigeria prefaced his condemnation with a "great sense of disappointment," because "no country had assisted the Third World more than the Soviet Union."